# ask session id is valid and active to web application

Tags: java, session, servlets, get

Is it possible to ask web application do you have this session id and its active ? I have 2 web application , first app has login security, second hasn't got and second we will open via redirecting to its link on first app. 
My aim is ;

1. i will put session id as parameter to second app's link like`www.secondApp.com/checkSession?sessionID=23132324242412`
2. when second app invoke , it will ask first app => "Is this session id is active ?" by using servlet.
3. first application will return an answer whether that session id is active or not

My problem is on second step , is it possible query all active sessions ?

Comment: Maybe try validating the session like,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634929/how-to-check-if-a-session-is-invalid

Comment: @Abhishek there is no function on that link that takes session id as parameter , they are checking requests session is active or not